# Aged beer, yeast

Tags: yeast, aging

I have aged my bourbon brown in secondary with bourbon and wood chips thrown in, it's been aging for 6 months now.  It's time to bottle, is there anything I need to do differently than normal before bottling ?  I have yeast nutrition that I could add couple of days before bottling, but is that really needed ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I'm trying to make sure is that I will have enough carbonation

Comment: I have brewed and bottled beer with wood chips before. The process was exactly like any other beer I did, except that I put wood chips in secondary. Why do you think it should be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long secondary, only change I world market would be to add fresh yeast slurry, either from vigorously fermenting batch, or from a packet of dry yeast.

Do **not** add nutrients now. There is a high chance yeast will not eat them and you will be left with nutrient taste.

Comment: I have a slurry from the first vessel, I can start that up with some LME and add before sugar and bottle.  Good to hear the no go on adding nutrients.